# Paypal Digital Goods, Transactions not displaying

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I've integrated Digital Goods with Express Checkout for my site and I've successfully tested with using sandbox. However I doesn't show any record of the transaction I've just completed in either the merchant account or the test account.

Should I be seeing a transaction? and if so, what could have gone wrong such that a transaction record isn't appearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most likely not calling the `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` API call to finalize the transaction.

DoExpressCheckoutPayment is a mandatory API call used to create a transaction out of a `TOKEN` and `PAYERID` (assuming the buyer has approved the transaction on the PayPal website).

The API doc (NVP) for DoExpressCheckoutPayment is available at [developer.paypal.com](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/).